# What are the specs for runways at international airports?

Tags: runways, airport-design, aircraft-maintenance

1) What are the materials that international airport runways are made of? If runways consists of several layers, what are they made of, and what is their depth and other specifications?

2) What are the surface specifications/properties required of such runways?

3) What kind of routine maintenance drills do such runways require?

Comment: This may provide some information: [Do runways need some special kind of tar or protective layer?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11841/do-runways-need-some-special-kind-of-tar-or-protective-layer/11847) (additional links included).

Comment: http://www.faa.gov/airports/engineering/construction_standards/

Comment: And for general info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runway#Pavement

Comment: And [here](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/9434/62) for the maintenance part

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. Runways for international airports are usually man made, which means that they are made up of asphalt or concrete and sometimes are a mixture of both. The depth for the runways are 29cm to 33cm.
2. Runways are usually around 150ft wide. For an international airport will have a runway around 6,000ft long, but depending on the size of the aircraft that land there a runway will need to be 8,000ft or more.
3. [I found this link](http://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Runway_Maintenance) which should give you information on runway maintenance.

Comment: 6,000 ft is a really _short_ runway. Even 8,000 ft is not that long. International airports usually have runways 10,000–12,000 ft long.

Comment: 33cm is about 13 inches. They've just built a new road near me and asphalt and concrete in the road are thicker than that. I'm pretty sure that a runway takes a more serious pounding than a highway - especially in the landing areas.

Comment: @JanHudec Yeah, 6,000 ft. is definitely quite short for a large passenger service airport. It's normal enough (even a bit long) for GA, but it's quite short for something that handles anything the size of a 737 or up. Orange County is a notable exception at ~5,700 ft.

Comment: @reirab It depends on what airport it is. Some international airports can only fly Q400's or smaller because there runway is so small.

Comment: @Ethan, that is why I said _usually_. It still does not make saying _around_ 6,000 ft any more correct though. _At least_ would be correct, because 12,000 is at least 6,000, but _around_ is not, because 12,000 is not around 6,000, it is twice as much.