# How often do large airports clean up the black stuff?

Tags: airport-markings, runway-contamination

Looking at Seattle International as an example, the first third of the runway is covered with a dark streak of tire material that accumulated from landings.

[image]

How often, if ever, is this cleaned up?  How is it done, and does it leave a lot behind after the cleaning process?

Does too much of this black material create a safety hazard in any way?

Comment: Related: [How is tire rubber removed from the runway?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/49613/how-is-tire-rubber-removed-from-the-runway)

Comment: Voted to close as a duplicate.